# Group by condition with no aggregate R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe, that I'd like to group by ID and DATE, but without any aggregation function.
Since my dataframe is like this

| ID | DATE | VAL 1 | VAL 2 | VAL 3 | VAL 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | 2018-02-08 01:00:00 | 10 | NA | NA | NA |
| ID1 | 2018-02-08 01:00:00 | NA | 30 | NA | NA |
| ID1 | 2018-02-08 01:00:00 | NA | NA | 90 | NA |
| ID1 | 2018-02-08 01:00:00 | NA | NA | NA | 60 |

What I'd like to do is shifting a the values of successive columns up, in order to have the values of the same DATE and of the same ID in a single row.

RESULT EXPECTED

| ID | DATE | VAL 1 | VAL 2 | VAL 3 | VAL 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID1 | 2018-02-08 01:00:00 | 10 | 30 | 90 | 60 |

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean with "aggregation function". Could you explain what you mean with that?

I would have done it like this, but I suspect that it's not what you are looking for?

```r
library(tidyverse)

d <-structure(list(ID = c("ID1", "ID1", "ID1", "ID1"), 
                   DATE = c("2018-02-08 01:00:00","2018-02-08 01:00:00", 
                            "2018-02-08 01:00:00", "2018-02-08 01:00:00"),
                   VAL.1 = c(10L, NA, NA, NA), 
                   VAL.2 = c(NA, 30L, NA, NA), 
                   VAL.3 = c(NA, NA, 90L, NA), 
                   VAL.4 = c(NA, NA, NA, 60L)), 
              class = "data.frame", 
              row.names = c(NA,-4L))

d %>% pivot_longer(-c("ID", "DATE")) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(value)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "name", values_from = "value")
#> # A tibble: 1 × 6
#>   ID    DATE                VAL.1 VAL.2 VAL.3 VAL.4
#>   <chr> <chr>               <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1 ID1   2018-02-08 01:00:00    10    30    90    60
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: The result is as you outputed the thing that i expect. I have the same ID and same DATE repeated over 10 row. Each column represents a measurement.

Comment: I'd like to perform this operation even if my field is NA

Comment: Can you provide an example, where my solution doesn't work? I am sorry, I don't quite understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Use `summarise` with `across` and `na.omit`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data |>
  group_by(ID, DATE) |>
  summarise(across(starts_with("VAL"), na.omit)) |>
  ungroup()
```

Or `fill` and `slice` (or `distinct`):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data |>
  group_by(ID, DATE) |>
  fill(starts_with("VAL"), .direction = "downup") |>
  slice(1) |>
  ungroup()
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 1 × 6
  ID    DATE        VAL1  VAL2  VAL3  VAL4
  <chr> <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 ID1   2018-02-08    10    30    90    60
```

Data:

```r
library(readr)

data <- read_table("ID  DATE    VAL1    VAL2    VAL3    VAL4
ID1 2018-02-08  10  NA  NA  NA
ID1 2018-02-08  NA  30  NA  NA
ID1 2018-02-08  NA  NA  90  NA
ID1 2018-02-08  NA  NA  NA  60")
``
```